# SqlExpress LocalDb can't open file

Tags: c#, ado.net, sql-server-express, localdb

I have two MDF files in a directory down the AppData/Local path.  If I attempt to open them using LocalDb.

My connection string is of the form:

> Data
>   Source=(localdb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\Anna\AppData\Local\CaseTrakker
>   Software\CTDynamoDisconnected\CTDynamoDisconnected_Data.mdf";Integrated
>   Security=True;Connect Timeout=10

I have a sample desktop application that attempts to connect to this MDF, and I get this exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database
>   "C:\USERS\ANNA\APPDATA\LOCAL\CASETRAKKER
>   SOFTWARE\CTDYNAMODISCONNECTED\CTDYNAMODISCONNECTED_DATA.MDF" requested
>   by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'IMA\Anna'.

If I move this file to any other location, or rename it (even to a name that is longer), I am able to connect to it.

There appears to be something peculiar about this location or something.

One other odd thing: it worked last week.  So far as I am aware, nothing has changed on my machine or my Domain Security.

I'm at a complete loss as to what else to even try.  Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Can you check if there is anything interesting in the LocalDB instance log file? It is located by default in `%localappdata%\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\v11.0` folder.

Comment: I'm not sure.  I see this: The service account is 'IMA\Anna'. This is an informational message; no user action is required.  Then, much later, I see this: Login failed for user 'IMA\Anna'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'C:\USERS\ANNA\APPDATA\LOCAL\CASETRAKKER SOFTWARE\CTDYNAMODISCONNECTED\CTDYNAMODISCONNECTED_DATA.MDF'. [CLIENT: <named pipe>]

Comment: Remember - if I simply rename the file, then it works just fine.  So, it isn't some security settings internal to the file.

Comment: I hoped there would be more about the reason why it failed to open the database. It could be something as simple as misnamed LDF file. Can you try running `select * from sys.databases` to see what name is this database attached as (I suspect there's something wrong with the metadata in master DB). Then you could just detach it with `sp_detach_db` and it should fix the problem. The next time you connect to it, `AttachDbFileName` will recreate the metadata from scratch.

Comment: I'm using LocalDb, so on startup, the DB is not attached in any way.  And, there is no LDF file on startup.

Comment: Have you tried running the command I provided? If the database have ever been connected to using LocalDB instance (in your case `(localdb)\v11.0`), it will be attached (registered) in this instance until explicitly dropped. This doesn't stop you from moving the file or attaching it to another LocalDB instance, but could interfere with the subsequent connection attempts.

Answer (score 1):

One cause of this problem is if you go into your `C:\Users\[username]` folder and delete the MDF and LDF files. If you do this, then that's akin to doing the same thing to full-blown SQL Server. The server instance still thinks it has the databases but they're obviously not going to work.

A work-around to the problem is to change the database name in your connection string and it should just work.

To actually fix the problem, open up SQL Management Studio, connect to server `(LocalDb)\v11.0` (likely with Windows Authentication) and you can detach these databases this way.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had that DB for a while and mistakenly deleted its MDF and LDF files.

To solve this, I opened **SQL Management Studio** and connected to `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB` using `Windows Authentication` then created manually a new empty DB with desired name like that in web.config connection string

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=myDb;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```